# Dynamic WITHIN clause on Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am using Gremlin on an Azure Cosmo DB and fairly new to it.

I am going to try to make things simple, my graph is something like that:

I have two types of vertices: `Identities` and `infos`. Infos are email and phone numbers that "define" identities as in edge.

ex:

```
[012-123-12345 =(defines)=> Identity 1]
[axel@test.com =(defines)=> Identity 1]
[axel@work.com =(defines)=> Identity 1]
[987-654-213 =(defines=> Identity 2]
```

An Identity can have an infinite number of phone numbers or emails. It can have 1 email and 0 phone number and vice versa

I am looking to get all identity Vertices that share **at least one** value (phone number or email) of with an other given Identity Vertice.

I know I can select all the values of a given identity (`id :1234`) in an array as: 
`g.V().hasLabel('identity').hasId('1234').in('defines').values('value')`

I know I can select all the identity vertices with  given email, phone list like:

`g.V('info').has('value',within('123342356','test@email.com')).out('defines')`

However, I don't manage to do something like : 
`g.V('info').has('value',
within(g.V().hasLabel('identity').hasId('1234').in('defines').values('value')))
.out('defines')`

Thanks for your help,

Axel

Answer (score 2):

When asking questions about Gremlin it is best to include a Gremlin script that creates some sample data as it provides a lot of context and allows for you to get a fully tested and working version of your traversal - like this:

```
g.addV('identity').property('name','ident1').as('1').
  addV('identity').property('name','ident2').as('2').
  addV('identity').property('name','ident3').as('3').
  addV('identity').property('name','ident4').as('4').
  addV('identity').property('name','ident5').as('5').
  addV('infos').property('info','321-333-1111').as('1111').
  addV('infos').property('info','321-333-2222').as('2222').
  addV('infos').property('info','321-333-3333').as('3333').
  addV('infos').property('info','321-333-4444').as('4444').
  addV('infos').property('info','321-333-1144').as('1144').
  addV('infos').property('info','321-333-5555').as('5555').
  addV('infos').property('info','1@here.com').as('1@').
  addV('infos').property('info','2@here.com').as('2@').
  addV('infos').property('info','3@here.com').as('3@').
  addV('infos').property('info','4@here.com').as('4@').
  addV('infos').property('info','35@here.com').as('35@').
  addE('defines').from('1111').to('1').
  addE('defines').from('2222').to('2').
  addE('defines').from('3333').to('3').
  addE('defines').from('4444').to('4').
  addE('defines').from('1144').to('1').
  addE('defines').from('1144').to('4').
  addE('defines').from('5555').to('5').
  addE('defines').from('1@').to('1').
  addE('defines').from('2@').to('2').
  addE('defines').from('3@').to('3').
  addE('defines').from('4@').to('4').
  addE('defines').from('35@').to('3').
  addE('defines').from('35@').to('5').iterate()
```

So, I gather from your question that you know the "identity" to start with and thus the "infos" that it defines:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('identity','name','ident4').in('defines').values('info')
==>321-333-4444
==>321-333-1144
==>4@here.com
```

If we want to know who else might share that, we just traverse back along those "defines" edges:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('identity','name','ident4').in('defines').out('defines').values('name')
==>ident4
==>ident4
==>ident4
==>ident1
```

You get 4 results because there were 4 edges traversed - count them up in the sample data. The duplication isn't so nice, so:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('identity','name','ident4').
......1>   in('defines').
......2>   out('defines').
......3>   dedup().
......4>   values('name')
==>ident4
==>ident1
```

Often `dedup()` isn't the best approach. It might be better to just eliminate that duplication during the traversal and in your case that might be better because you already know the "start identity" and its existence. What I gather you want are the other "identity" vertices that you aren't aware of.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('identity','name','ident4').as('exists').
......1>   in('defines').
......2>   out('defines').
......3>   where(neq('exists')).
......4>   values('name')
==>ident1
```

Note that we get no results when an "identity" shares no "infos":

```
gremlin> g.V().has('identity','name','ident2').as('exists').
......1>   in('defines').
......2>   out('defines').
......3>   where(neq('exists')).
......4>   values('name')
gremlin>
```

If you'd like to see the data that is matched then and the "identity" it matched to then:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('identity','name','ident3').as('exists').
......1>   in('defines').as('shared').
......2>   out('defines').as('matched').
......3>   where(neq('exists')).
......4>   select('matched','shared').
......5>     by('name').
......6>     by('info')
==>[matched:ident5,shared:35@here.com]
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your answer! It helps a lot and point out the fact that I may not have build my graph in the most efficient way. Indeed I had plan on duplicating the « infos » modes so that they are always connected to only a single identity node . ThAts ‘s why I was looking to compare the values rather than traversing the graph. Just for my curiosity, is there a way to compare values like I tried to do it? Thanks!

Comment: It's not much of a graph query then. Perhaps there's a way to write that all as one traversal, but for readability, i'd just do two separate traversals: the first to get the "infos" to store in a list then pass that list to `within()` in your second traversal.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks Stephen